# Detect audio coming in through Linphone

Tags: ios, swift, voip, linphone

I need to show a button on the screen when my device has audio coming in on a Linphone call. Is it possible to show when audio is actively coming in?

Answer (score 0):

these two function can indicate, if is even possible to have audio in current call. Without payload or if audio direction is for example Invalid there is no chance to have audio.

```
linphone_call_params_get_audio_direction(LinphoneCallParams)

linphone_call_params_get_used_audio_payload_type(LinphoneCallParams)
```

After you can take from given call audio stats and extract downloaded bandwidth. When downloaded bandwidth is greater then zero, indicate that some audio is running in call.

```
LinphoneCallStats * audioStats = linphone_call_get_audio_stats(LinphoneCall)
float downloadedBandwidth = linphone_call_stats_get_download_bandwidth(audioStats)
```